# how to make a Door and key prefab in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How would I go about to make a prefab with both the door and the key wth the key only opening the door it was dragged in with and not other doors if I had more than one prefab.

so instead of door which i used as an example i have keys which interact with other objects ex. water, rock, vines which are the "doors".

```
public List<GameObject> rockList = new List<GameObject>();

// Use this for initialization
private void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();

    isMounted = false;

    water = GameObject.Find("water");
    freezeWaterKey = GameObject.Find("freezeWaterKey");

    moveRockKey = GameObject.Find("moveRockKey");
    rock = GameObject.Find("rock");


    waterBoundary = GameObject.Find("golemBoundary");
    moveRockKey = GameObject.Find("moveRockKey");

    vine = GameObject.Find("Vines");
    vineKey = GameObject.Find("key_vine");
}

private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && (other.tag == "Golem") && (isMounted == false))
    {
        isMounted = true;

        //Change the Name of instantiated Clone
        GameObject mountedGolemClone =
            Instantiate(mountedGolem, golem.transform.position, golem.transform.rotation) as GameObject;
        mountedGolemClone.name = "mountedGolem";

        Destroy(mage);
        Destroy(golem);
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C) && !freezeWaterKey && (other.tag == "waterTrigger"))
    {
        Renderer rend = water.GetComponent<Renderer>();
        rend.material = frozenWaterMaterial;
        Destroy(waterBoundary);
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C) && !moveRockKey && (other.tag == "rockTrigger"))
    {
        rb.AddForce(transform.right*-1*rockThrust);
        Debug.Log("force");
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C) && !vineKey && (other.tag == "vineTrigger"))
    {
        Destroy(vine);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of just asking for answer, why don't you give it a go first. I suggest having a look at tags to get you started.

Comment: I'm currently working on it now because every door and key prefab will have the same tag then one key can open any door with multiple instances of the prefab.

Comment: i just want to be able to drag and drop one prefab which contains the door and the key and have that key only work with that door and not other instances of  the same prefab.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: You could have a separate door and key prefab, then on the door have a public gameobject that checks for a key and drag this in the inspector. Then have code that checks ontrigger or whatever you are using if the player has this object.

Comment: yea i could try that im just trying to make it easy for my team

Comment: That's probably the easiest way, you could also use strings and the key when picked up could add a string to an array on the player. Then on the door have a string and if the string matches the door would open. This way can lead to frustration as the string would have to match perfectly and would allow for human error, but might be easier for a team not experienced in Unity.

Another way would be to have the door unlock when the trigger or pickup is done on the key. Have a public gameobject that is tied to the door and open the door on this interaction.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a different script on both the objects, i.e. A "Key" script on the key and a "Door" script on the door.

Now in both of these scripts give a public variable like "keyNo" and "doorNo".

After dragging your prefab in the screen, you could set the value of these variables to be the same for a pair of door and a key.

Then, in your script, check if the keyNo is equal to the doorNo. If yes, unlock.